# 3 column layout not getting columns aligned right

Tags: css, html

I don't know if it would be hard to explain but here it goes.. I have a number of divs on my page and I want them to come in a column layout. The page has a nav bar, a logo, some profile data and 3 more divs. Those 3 divs are not getting aligned correctly. I want those all three of them `#content-1, #content-2, #content-3` in a horizontal manner in a straight line.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wJ2ef/). Better to look [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wJ2ef/show/) at the result.

**CSS:**

```
 @CHARSET"ISO-8859-1";
 html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
}
#content {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
#content-1, #content-2, #content-3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
#content-1 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}
#content-2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
#content-3 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}
.user_small_card p.name {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.user_small_card p.profession {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.userWrap {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.user_card {
    width: 77% !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.major_data {
    width: 80%;
}
.major_data .profile_box p:first-child {
    border-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.major_data .profile_box p:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: justify;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.major_data .profile_box p {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.commitment_box {
    text-align: center;
    height: 390px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.commitment_box .commitment p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.commitment_box .commitment p:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
@CHARSET"ISO-8859-1";
 .userWrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}
.userWrap:hover {
    z-index: 2;
}
.user {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s, background-color 1s;
}
.user:hover {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: width 0.3s ease 0.5s, height 0.3s ease 0.5s, background-color 2.3s;
    background: #eee;
}
.user img {
    float: left;
}
.user .name, .skills {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.user .name {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.user_card {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 38%;
    padding: 10px;
    display:table;
}
.user_card p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:30px;
    padding:2px 10px 2px 2px;
    color: #aaa;
}
.user_card div {
    display:table-row;
    padding:2px;
}
.user_card div div {
    display:table-cell;
}
.user_card div div.progress_wrap {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.user_card div div.progress {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-1">
            <div id="content-1-1">
                <div class="user_small_card">
                    <img src="img/user.png" width="150" height="150" />
                    <p class="name">Arkam Gadet</p>
                    <p class="profession">Photographer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content-1-2">
                <div id="people_worked_with">
                        <h2>People worked with</h2>

                    <div class="userWrap">
                        <div class="user">
                            <img src="img/user.png" width="50" height="50" />   <span class="name">Danish</span>

                            <br/>   <span class="skills">Coder, Programmer</span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="userWrap">
                        <div class="user">
                            <img src="img/user.png" width="50" height="50" />   <span class="name">Danish</span>

                            <br/>   <span class="skills">Coder, Programmer</span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="userWrap">
                        <div class="user">
                            <img src="img/user.png" width="50" height="50" />   <span class="name">Danish</span>

                            <br/>   <span class="skills">Coder, Programmer</span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="userWrap">
                        <div class="user">
                            <img src="img/user.png" width="50" height="50" />   <span class="name">Danish</span>

                            <br/>   <span class="skills">Coder, Programmer</span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content-2">
            <div id="content-2-1">
                <div class="user_card">
                    <div class="skills">
                        <p>Skills</p>
                        <div class="progress_wrap">
                            <div class="progress" style="width:95%"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="commitment">
                        <p>Commitment</p>
                        <div class="progress_wrap">
                            <div class="progress" style="width:4%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="reputation">
                        <p>Reputation</p>
                        <div class="progress_wrap">
                            <div class="progress" style="width:5%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content-2-2">
                <div class="major_data">
                    <div class="profile_box">
                        <p>About</p>
                        <p>This is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about me</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile_box">
                        <p>About</p>
                        <p>This is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about me</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile_box">
                        <p>About</p>
                        <p>This is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about meThis is about me</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content-3">
            <div id="content-3-1">
                <div class="commitment_box">
                    <div class="commitment">
                        <p>Alex:</p>
                        <p>Lorizzle ipsum away fo shizzle daahng dawg, consectetizzle adipiscing elit. Nullam sapien velizzle, bow wow wow volutpizzle, crunk gizzle, gravida vizzle, arcu. Dope check it out for sure. Sed erizzle. Gangsta izzle dolor dapibizzle nizzle tempus black. Fo shizzle pellentesque nibh izzle dizzle. Crazy izzle tortizzle.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="commitment">
                        <p>Alex 1:</p>
                        <p>Vivamizzle nec we gonna chung egizzle nisi izzle pretium. Daahng dawg sizzle amet lacus. Uhuh ... yih! eu nizzle eget lacizzle auctizzle yo. Praesent gizzle viverra crunk. Curabitizzle ghetto arcu. Vestibulizzle enim uhuh ... yih!, the bizzle pimpin', congue , sheezy nizzle, libero. Nullam vitae pede rizzle</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="commitment">
                        <p>Alex 2:</p>
                        <p>In sagittis leo stuff nisi. Shizzlin dizzle rhoncizzle, arcu check out this malesuada facilisizzle, dizzle nulla uhuh ... yih! shut the shizzle up, da bomb auctizzle cool felizzle a break yo neck, yall. Check out this volutpizzle fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle augue. I saw beyonces tizzles and my pizzle went</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="commitment">
                        <p>Alex 3:</p>
                        <p>crizzle yippiyo. Maecenizzle tortor vel fo. Phasellus lobortizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle things gizzle, shiznit nec, mah nizzle sure amizzle, pulvinar egestizzle, crazy. Vivamus mofo. Vestibulizzle ante doggy primizzle izzle own yo' break yo neck, yall luctizzle yo mamma ghetto posuere that's the shizzle</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="commitment">
                        <p>Alex 4:</p>
                        <p>Vestibulizzle shiznit ipsizzle primizzle black mofo orci its fo rizzle izzle ultricizzle posuere cool Curae; Sed vitae nulla quizzle ma nizzle ornare shiz. Phasellizzle get down get down da bomb. Praesent volutpizzle accumsan velizzle. Mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa mammasay mammasa m</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problems:

1. First column is coming down a bit
2. Third column is coming down a bit

How can bring the first and third in a line with the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make change into this line into css

```
#content-1, #content-2, #content-3 {    
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `float: left` to  #content-1 and `float: right` to #content-3

Add the following CSS:

```
#content-1 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#content-2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
#content-3 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

[Update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wJ2ef/2/)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui You're welcome.  His solution is clean and simple, missed it :)

Answer (score 1):

i hope you are looking like this :- http://jsfiddle.net/wJ2ef/4/

With the using of `float` you can proper align your **Div Elements**

Comment: that's what I did before but then I had to use column based layout :(

Comment: oh alright than you can go for manoj's answer thats suits your requirement :-)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it like this:

```
#content-1, #content-2, #content-3 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "display: inline-block;" to:

```
#content-1, #content-2, #content-3 {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#content-1, #content-2, #content-3 {    
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: An answer solely consisting of code with no or little explanation makes it difficult to understand which mistakes the asker made or which approach the asker should take and why your answer is viable. Please add explanations to your code.